# A more elegant proof that $f$ is a polynomial (may be using Cauchy Estimates).

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function, and it satisfies $$|f(x)| \leq A + B|z|^k$$ for all complex numbers $z,$ where $A,B,$ and $k$ are positive numbers. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Here is a trial for the solution:

> [image]
> [image]

Is there a more elegant proof for this question?

Also, I have another question, should $k$ be a positive integer instead of just being a positive number?

Comment: For your second question: if $k$ is any positive real number, then the same proof shows that the function must be a polynomial of degree at most $\lfloor k\rfloor$.

Comment: This perfect seems perfectly elegant to me! It's a simple extension of the proof of Liouville's theorem on bounded entire functions. I feel like there's some alternate proof that's analogous to the fundamental theorem of algebra. If $f(z_0)=0$, then one can consider $f(z)/(z-z_0)$ and induct on $k$. I don't remember how to handle the case where $f$ has no zeros. (We don't automatically have $|f(z)|\to\infty$ as $z\to\infty$, so we can't finish by considering $1/f(z)$. We could consider $\log f(z)$, and the Liouville-type proof will show that it's constant, but then why not your proof itself)

Comment: The problem can be reduced to the Liouville theorem by subtracting from $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ the polynomial $\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor k\rfloor} a_nz^n$ and dividing by  $z^{\lfloor k\rfloor+1}.$

Comment: Rouche's theorem implies that, for $g(z)=Bz^k$, a polynomial, and $\hat{f}=f-A$, $\hat{f}+g$ has $0<k'\leq k$ zeroes in some disc $D(0,r)$. Hence $\hat{f}+g=P(z)*Q(z)$ where $P$ is a polynomial with $k'$ zeroes. Hence $Q$ is never 0. But since $P$ and $g$ have the same degree, $Q$ is in fact bounded ($\forall$ $r$ I might add), and thus constant, and thus Q is a polynomial, finally $f=PQ-g+A$ is a polynomial also.